# How can i remove white space at right of site

Tags: css, wordpress

http://www.youthintelligentsia.org/yi-new/

how can i remove space at the right side of this site

This is wordpress site ample theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   html, body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: it simply disappear the horizontal scroll, but didn't remove the space

Comment: The whitespace I see now is .flexslider {
    border: 0px ;
} should fix it

Comment: lol,
i just found it's a browser issue
ur code did worked
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You have `max-width:1800px;` in `.main-head-wrap`

Comment: change it to `max-width:100%;`

Comment: you put back the 1800px. It was fixed with the 100%. I saw it

Comment: If you don't see a change, do a hard refresh. `Ctrl+Shift+R` for Windows and `Cmd+Shift+R` for Mac

Comment: BTW, `display:block;` is not `clearfix`. You should look it up. Will save you a lot of issues in the future.

Comment: see now, i also refreshed it

Comment: yeah it looks fixed on mine. try it on a different browser

Comment: no i do not see any small spaces. The only space I see to the right is from the scrollbar

Comment: yup,
it's a browser issue

Comment: lol,
Thanks for help budy
but i just found out something else worked
see the answer which i have accepted